# Uncaught Google_Exception: (update) unknown parameter: 'copyRequiresWriterPermission'

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to disable the direct download of files in Google Drive by setting 'copyRequiresWriterPermission' but I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught Google_Exception: (update) unknown parameter: 'copyRequiresWriterPermission'
```

I'm using the following to first share the file, and then disable direct download for that file:

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setType("anyone");
$newPermission->setRole("reader");
$share_file = $gd_service->permissions->create( $fileId, $newPermission );
# share OK
$emptyFileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$disable_dl_file = $gd_service->files->update( $fileId, $emptyFileMetadata, ['copyRequiresWriterPermission'=>true] );
```

I don't know if the body should have another format in order for it to work (sadly the [V3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) lacks examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an evening of trial-and-error I found out the following works

```
$emptyFileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(['copyRequiresWriterPermission'=>true]);
$disable_dl_file = $gd_service->files->update( $fileId, $emptyFileMetadata );
```

Comment: You saved my day bro! Same issue but with another parameter - writersCanShare